# Says "Installing system" but not doing anything

Tags: 11.10, installation

I'm installing 11.10 on a homemade system with Intel motherboard and 1 GB RAM. It downloaded packages but now it's at "Installing system" with about 10% of the status bar left and it's doing nothing. CD-ROM is not flashing, hard drive is not flashing. The little circle thing just spins. Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Is it possible to change to a console and check the syslogs for messages? Does CTRL+ALT+F1 work? What about other consoles (F2-7)?

Comment: Did you do an upgrade? Or did you download an image and installed this? If so, did you check [md5sum](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes)?

Answer (score 0):

If you enabled to download / install third party programs (one of the two options at the start of the installation) try to restart the installation without enabling any of the two options.